# Copying from comments to answer using SO app

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-app

I was trying to copy a comment in order to add it to an answer but I couldn’t get this to work.

I can use the copy button from the comments context menu, but when I try to paste it into an answer I obtain just empty text.

Perhaps I’m wrong but this seems a bug to me.

I’m using the iPhone SO app (12.1 iOS version) , and I would like to know if it happens to someone else, and if it also happens on Android phones.

Comment: I think that development for mobile apps is mostly abandoned at this point.

Comment: @yivi I think it's a pity because I happen to use it very much, I find it useful

Comment: I only keep it around for the notifications. For everything else, I find the mobile/responsive view a superior experience.

Comment: a new version of the mobile app should be released that simply shows a notification, and then sends you to your browser app of choice

Comment: AFAIK, the apps aren't in development, but they [are being patched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303856/332043). There's just no new features being added.

Comment: @Zoe Well, at least in iOS there hasn't been a release in about a year.

Comment: @yivi [this is the latest situation posted by Tim Posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317707/241919): "There are no plans to resume development in the near future. [...] We'll continue to support critical bugs in the interim, but no *new work* is planned."

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I'm aware of that. I'm also aware of the app not getting updates in the last year.